# How do I get windows 7 to go full screen in boot camp?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, boot-camp

I'm running Windows 7 on an iMac using Bootcamp. At the native resolution of 1290x1200, the desktop fills the entire screen, but when I run games at a lower resolution or reduce the size of the desktop the visible area is reduced and a large black border surrounds the display.

I want to run 1024x768 full screen, not letterboxed. Is there a way to do this? I suspect a problem with the drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know in Nvidia driver settings you can set the video scaling in there to stretch, do not scale or use monitor built in scaling.

I would suggest looking into your graphics card's control panel and searching through the video scaling options.

Comment: I did a driver update and everything is working now. The default boot camp drivers for windows 7 do not allow scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Your video card is unsupported by Boot Camp, so you need to manually update the drivers. It can be done in a moment.